# Javascript date/time string to sql date time

Tags: javascript, date, mariadb, type-conversion

I am passing a date time:

```
    2015-12-23T09:57:00.000Z
```

To a stored procedure in mariaDB.  The stored procedure doesn't like the javascript date/time, how do I convert the date/time for use in the stored procedure?

I've been playing around with 'str_to_date':

```
    select str_to_date('2015-12-23T09:57:00.000Z', '%Y-%M-%dT%h:%i:%s');
```

However this returns (NULL).

Comment: Try sending it as string using `Date.toLocaleString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Alternative
pass string into stored procedure and then in sql convert to datetime like this:

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME,REPLACE(REPLACE('2015-12-23T09:57:00.000Z','T',' '),'Z',''))
```

Comment: This works, as long as you add the conversion type:        SELECT CONVERT(REPLACE(REPLACE('2015-12-23T09:57:00.000Z','T', ' '), 'Z', ''), DATETIME);

Answer (score 1):

You can use timestamp, in JS get UNIX timestamp like so

```
var now = new Date(),
    unixTimestamp = Math.floor(now.getTime() / 1000);
    // JS operates with miliseconds, divide by 1000 to get seconds
```

And in mariaDB use function [`FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Answer (score 0):

Your `%M` should have been `%m`.

Another approach:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date(LEFT('2015-12-23T09:57:00.000Z',19), '%Y-%m-%dT%h:%i:%s') |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2015-12-23 09:57:00                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you have 5.6.4 or later:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('2015-12-23T09:57:00.987Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%h:%i:%s.%f') |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2015-12-23 09:57:00.987000                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```